# Can ping, but not map by IP address

Tags: windows

I have the strangest problem.

This is a Server 2016 VM install on a 2016 Hyper-V host. The other day I had a problem with an update, and it broke RRAS. I had to delete it, and reinstall it. I also removed and re-added the Hyper-V network card for the VM only.

The 2016 VM is a domain controller, and has one of the two DNS servers, but I do not think it has anything to do with DNS.

The network interfaces are 192.168.100.24 (main) and the RRAS adapter is 192.168.100.134.

Since that happened, I can open a network location in "Start>Run" using \192.168.100.134 (or a NETBIOS name), but not \192.168.100.24, which is the internal main network card.

The firewall is not an issue since I have tried this with it disabled, but I doing this from the actual server on itself anyway. I CAN ping it from any computer, but cannot \192.168.100.24 from any computer, again, even itself.

This is causing problems with various hard-coded IP addresses that have been there forever.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: For the record, my handle has nothing to do with phishing, and predates it by years.

In chess, a "fish" is a weak player, and the "joke" is that I am a "fish", aka "phish"among chess masters. I have been PhishMaster since 1997 on the Internet Chess Club, and now other sites since.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

No matter what I did, including editing the registry directly, "NetBIOS over Tcpip" said "disabled".

I removed the VM's adapter, and re-added it. I then went into device manager, and removed all the hidden adapters, especially the one I just took out that was having the problems. I went in and reset all the new adapter to the static IP address, and other info, and it showed "NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled".

After that, \192.168.100.24 worked fine.